# PowerShell Script to add newuser

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I made this Line to add new users but the AD doesnt enable my account

```
New-ADUser (Read-Host "Enter Username") -AccountPassword (Read-Host -AsSecureString "Enter Password") | Enable-ADAccount
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617253.aspx) for `New-ADUser` cmdlet you can see the following buried in the parameter description for `-passthru`:

> By default (i.e. if -PassThru is not specified), this cmdlet does not generate any output.

Which you can also see in practice.

```
PS C:\Users\matt> new-aduser "matt"

PS C:\Users\matt>
```

You are essentially passing $null to `Enable-ADAccount` which is why nothing appears to be happening. You need to use the `-PassThru` switch, as stated above, then it should work.

```
PS C:\Users\matt> new-aduser "matt" -PassThru


DistinguishedName : CN=matt,CN=Users,DC=DOMAIN,DC=NET
Enabled           : False
GivenName         : 
Name              : matt
ObjectClass       : user
ObjectGUID        : 914fccdc-11ce-442e-b247-e4fd24f90023
SamAccountName    : matt
SID               : S-1-5-21-961215277-3068250917-3774519051-11002
Surname           : 
UserPrincipalName :
```

Comment: I think you have to use the PassThru switch.  See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617253.aspx.  "Returns the new user object when the PassThru parameter is specified. By default, this cmdlet does not generate any output."

Comment: How can i set that new user must change his password at the next logon, at the same line command above

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
New-ADUser (Read-Host "Enter UserName") -AccountPassword (Read-Host -AsSecureString "Enter Password") -Enabled:$true
```

I've never piped a new user account anywhere, but you can enable the account in the same line.